# русские буквы jsp

Tags: jsp, hibernate, spring-mvc

когда вывожу поле entity объекта не отображает русский.
если же вывожу просто стринговую переменную то все норм.
Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
    public String list(HttpServletRequest request) throws DalException{
        List <Item> item = crudDao.list(Item.class);

        request.setAttribute("items", item);
        request.setAttribute("l", "фывфыв");
        return "list";

    }
```

JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<div style="width:700px;margin:auto">
<table>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="<c:url value="/pageview?index=${item.getId() }"/>"><c:out value="${item.model}" /></a><br><img src="<c:url value="/getimage?index=${item.getId() }"/>"height="160" width="120"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${item.opisanie}" /><c:out value="${l }" /></td>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

форма:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<div style="width:700px;margin:auto">
<spring:url value="addi" var="add" />
<form:form action="${add}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="uploadForm" >
<h1>Модель</h1>
<input type="text" name="model">
<h1>Марка</h1>
<input type="text" name="marka">
<h1>Описание</h1>
<input type="text" name="opisanie">
<h1>Жесткость</h1>
<input type="text" name="jestkost">
<h1>Высота</h1>
<input type="text" name="visota">
<h1>цена</h1>
<input type="text" name="cena">
<h1>размер</h1>
<input type="text" name="razmer">
<br>

<br>
<h1>Картинка</h1>
<input type="file" name="files[0]" accept="image/*,image/jpeg">

<br>
<input type="submit" name="additem" value="add"/>
</form:form>
<a href="<c:url value="/list"/>">spisok</a>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: использую бд h2, utf-8. вопрос открыт

Comment: Вообще я больше спрашивал не про то какая там кодировка, а соотносится ли эта кодировка с тем что реально хранится в таблице, Т.е. вот когда вы получаете данные в список item, строковые значения нормальные?

Comment: @Vartlok вывел в консоль, вопросы вместо символов

Comment: Ну вот и ответ, возможно вы когда сохраняли указали что-то не то. PS. удалить комментарий можно нажав на крестик справа от времени.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я получаю данные с формы уже в плохом формате. добавил код формы.

Comment: А что видно в браузере при сабмите формы?

Comment: отображает нормально. Не может быть изза этого enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: Нет. Отображается то оно нормально, но, что посылается и что принимается на стороне сервера? Поставе бряку в методе, который обрабатывает сохранение и посмотрите какие там значения.

Comment: Я поставил System.out.println(request.getParameter("marka")); , выводит вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Добавил filter:

```
package by.lesson11.filters;



import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class CharsetFilter implements Filter
 {
 private String encoding;

 public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException
 {
  encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");

  if( encoding==null ) encoding="UTF-8";
 }

 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain       next)
 throws IOException, ServletException
 {
  // Respect the client-specified character encoding
  // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
  if(null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
    request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);


  /**
* Set the default response content type and encoding
*/
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");


  next.doFilter(request, response);
 }

  public void destroy(){}
 }
```

замапил его под все запросы:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>by.lesson11.filters.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```